# Show suggestions when I type questions on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, duplicate-suggestions

Recently, I have got lots of questions closed as duplicate because of that. I think, it's time this feature should be added to mobile site as smartphones can handle that today (my mid-range Android smartphone can handle that on desktop site).

Comment: How ironical !!

Comment: @ysts1 Haha.. This question has also been closed as duplicate.. :)